# Help for drawing graphs in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, graphs

How do I graph something like that in `LaTeX`?

[image: with boxes around the Name would be nice]

This is the code I've got so far.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style=. 
    {rectangle,thick,draw}]
    \node (Frau) at (0,0) {A};
    \node (Master) at (0,3) {B};
    \node (EUR) at (5,3) {C};
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[>={Stealth[black]},
              every node/.style={fill=white,rectangle},
              every edge/.style={draw=red,very thick}]
    \path [->] (Frau) edge node {$5$} (EUR);
    \path [->] (Frau) edge node {$3$} (Master);
    \path [->] (Master) edge node {$4$} (EUR);
     \end{scope}
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! See `tiz-cd` package.

Comment: you have extra "." in here `\begin{scope}[every node/.style=.`